# python 3, how to fix the frequency of occurrence

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, word-frequency

I would like to write a function named "frequency" which can fix the frequency of pairs in the second half of my output, for example if I fix the frequency of the couple ['A', 'C'] at 0,5 and the frequency of the couple ['M', 'K'] at 0,5, I would like an output like following:

```
['A', 'K']
    ['A', 'K']
    ['A', 'K']
    ['A', 'K']
    ['A', 'K']
    ['A', 'C']
    ['A', 'C']
    ['A', 'C']
    ['M', 'K']
    ['M', 'K']
    ['M', 'K']
```

I would like to change easily the value of the frequency I set. I tried to build a Function for this purpose, but I just could count the frequency of the existing couples, without fixing them.

the code I have is the following:

```
for i in range(int(lengthPairs/2)):
    pairs.append([aminoacids[0], aminoacids[11]])
print(int(lengthPairs/2))

for j in range(int(lengthPairs/2)+1):
    dictionary = dict()
    r1 = randrange(20)
    r2 = randrange(20)
    pairs.append([aminoacids[r1], aminoacids[r2]])

for pair in pairs:
    print (pair)
```

where:

```
aminoacids = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']
lengthPairs = 10
pairs = list(list())
```

it gives me an output like this:

```
['A', 'K']
['A', 'K']
['A', 'K']
['A', 'K']
['A', 'K']
['A', 'C']
['M', 'K']
['I', 'I']
['F', 'G']
['V', 'H']
['V', 'I']
```

thank you very much for any assistance!

Comment: Why not dump the number of each you want, then shuffle to mix them up?

Comment: You need to describe what you mean better than "fix the frequency a 0,5" What does the "0,5" mean? 0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my best to understand what you meant. And let's see if the following does what you want:

```
aminoacids = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']

pair_fq_change = [aminoacids[0], aminoacids[11]] #the pair that you'd like to change the frequency, e.g. ['A', 'K']

original_pairs = [['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['B', 'C']]


def frequency(original_pairs, pair_fq_change, fq):
'''fq is the number of frequency that you want the pair_fq_change to have'''
    updated_pairs = []
    count = 0
    for pair in original_pairs:
        if pair != pair_fq_change:
            updated_pairs.append(pair)
        elif pair == pair_fq_change and count < fq:
            updated_pairs.append(pair)
            count += 1
        else:
            continue
    return updated_pairs        

updated_pairs = frequency(original_pairs, pair_fq_change, 3)
print(updated_pairs)

>>>[['D', 'E'], ['S', 'F'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['A', 'K'], ['B', 'C']]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! Yes, I was looking for something like that. It's not exactly what I have to do, but now I can easily modify your function. thanks a lot! It's not always easy for me to explain exactly what I want to do.. you really made my day! thanks again

Comment: @laura You are welcome. And I would appreciate if you vote for my answer by clicking the up-arrow.

Comment: I can't do that because I need more reputation, I'm sorry!